# Pressing Tab for autocompleting the directory name in terminal, appens a space after the directory name and not a "/" sign

Tags: 12.04

When I use "cd" command to move to certain directory in terminal, I press Tab button to autocomplete the directory name, and a "/" sign appends at the end. But, when I use some other command (say "mv"), clicking on Tab button to autocomplete the directory name, autocompletes the directory name, but does not append "/" after it, but a space. So, I have to manually delete the space by pressing Backspace button and type "/". But, in my friend's laptop, it does not occur. Whichever command he uses, he always gets "/" after presing Tab button to autocomplete the directory name. Please tell how to solve this problem. I have freshly installed 12.04 LTS version.

See the screenshot here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9dhwm5Go59HZnFITmloVjZwcGs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am not concerned with the file. The directory is there, pressing Tab button is autocompleting the correct directory name, but the problem is that at last it is not appending "/", but a space.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution to my problem at this link: [Tab autocomplete in terminal is not behaving properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117159/tab-autocomplete-in-terminal-is-not-behaving-properly). Now, my problem is solved. Thanks to all for giving suggestions.